# Search databinded listboxitem from XmlNode

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm working on a c# wpf app in which I databind a listbox control to an xml datasource. Now I know that I can find the XmlNode that is linked to a listboxitem using datacontext. But now I want to go the other way around: Find the associated listboxitem when I have an xmlnode..

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

for each listboxitem, you retrieve the XmlNode, then, you use .Equals() on the node you have...

Comment: Thanks, hope it's not too memory heavy though, I'll try a parallel foreach then